# Creating an extension in Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have worked through the 'getting started' instructions on https://github.com/spree/spree and am able to get my app up and running, but when I try to create my own extension using the command:

```
spree extension simple_sales
```

It throws off the following:

```
  create  spree_simple_sales/bin
  create  spree_simple_sales/bin/rails
  create  spree_simple_sales/spree_simple_sales.gemspec

(erb):5:in `template': uninitialized constant #<Class:#<SpreeCmd::Extension:0x00000001497f40>>::Spree (NameError)
from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
from /home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
from /home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@4.2.6v1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
```

Can anyone let me know whats causing this? Apologies, it is probably something pretty basic!

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find out more? I ran into the same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same error on `spree -v 3.0.8` and workaround for this problem was to install `spree -v 3.0.7`, so the steps are:

```
gem install spree -v 3.0.7
spree _3.0.7_ extension simple_sales
```

Also i created an [issue](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/7237) on github, so you can track it.

Comment: Thanks mate. Using 3.0.7 worked for me. I've added some comments to the github issue.

Comment: Great @vishes_shell, I also commented on the issue.